# How do you create a .XPI package on a mac

Tags: macos, file, xpi

How do you create a .XPI package on a mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XPI files are just ZIP-files](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~piaip/docs/CreateMozApp/mozilla-chp-6-sect-3.html) that have been renamed with extension xpi. You can just use the file compression available through the Finder UI or use commands in terminal or automate process using makefiles or similar.

Comment: Dead link. Fortunately, we've got the Web archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20100529053725/http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~piaip/docs/CreateMozApp/mozilla-chp-6-sect-3.html

Answer (score 1):

use the xpi builder: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/builder

Answer (score 0):

see [this makefile](http://web.archive.org/web/20100125052931/arjansnaterse.nl/build-script-firefox-extensions-mac-os) for example, a xpi is only a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up any zip tools and can make xpi,

I use [7zip](http://7-zip.org/) for that, for example

```
7za a -tzip myextension.xpi chrome install.rdf install.js -r -mx9
```