# Package Firefox XPI without Mac hidden files

Tags: macos, firefox-addon

Mac OS creates `.DS_Store` hidden files, among others. I've created a Firefox addon that runs just fine, but when I send it to the Validator, I get warnings asking me to delete the hidden files. I've turned on hidden files and attempted to just delete them and repackage the addon, but the files just reappear a few seconds later. How can I delete these files and package my extension to avoid these warnings?

Note: this question shouldn't be considered a duplicate of this question: [How do you create a .XPI package on a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130324/how-do-you-create-a-xpi-package-on-a-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. I ended up packing my extension using the 7-zip based app [Keka](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/). It has the option to exclude hidden files.